# Return JsonNet type JSON from WebAPI in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-web-api, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

In standard MVC I use JsonNet to return JSON that is in camelCase and sucessfully serializes entities that have related entities (which otherwise reports a "cycles" error" using the default serializer).

I'd like to do the same for a WebAPI controller in an Orchard module.  By default it returns PascalCase JSON and reports a "cyles" exception when given a list of entities.

Can anyone explain how best to configure the JSON output from within the Orchard module, to mimic what JsonNet would produce?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround, which is to set the JSON formatters settings to camelCase in an ActionFilter:

```
    public class CamelCaseJsonAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var jsonFormatter = actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

But this seems inefficient, as it gets set on each request, rather than globally, once.

I'm guessing there is an extensibility point somewhere in a module to set the HttpConfiguration - can anyone tell me one way or the other?

Many thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, current version of Orchard does not provide DI-based filters/configuration providers for WebAPI controllers the way it does for MVC ones. This feature is something we want to implement shortly - not for 1.7 for sure, 1.7.1 maybe. Till then you need to either set up a global config, use attributes or attach to Autofac registration to set custom controller configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Piotr.  Useful to know this is on the roadmap.