# How to add a Delegating Handler to my Module?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, orchardcms-1.7

I am developing a module that has a web-api controller.

If i am correct, in the case of attributes, they get fired when we the class/method gets decorated. 
However, how will this work for delegateHandlers?

How can i access the HttpConfiguration?

Thanks

Comment: So it seems orchard has not implemented just yet this. have to stick to attributes. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447058/return-jsonnet-type-json-from-webapi-in-orchard

Answer (score 0):

So it seems orchard has not implemented just yet this. have to stick to attributes. 
[return json from orchardCMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447058/return-jsonnet-type-json-from-webapi-in-orchard)